iOS Notification Service Extension with Audio Thumbnail
I am using a Notification Service Extension in my application, and I am successfully able to display images and videos. However, when I pass an audio URL, a default audio player appears after a long press. Is it possible to show a thumbnail for audio content before a long tap in the notification center?
